# Difference between GMT and UTC

Tags: asp.net, .net, datetime

Clients registers and selects his time zone GMT +1 
On a form clients input date and time 1 May 2019 5:00 PM 
We subtract 1 hour from the input time and save it to the DB
So the time saved is 1 May 2019 4:00 PM 
Is this time UTC 0

The server time zone is set to UTC 0

So my question is adding and subtracting based on GMT offset makes the time universal time or anything else is required ?

Also methods in .net like ToUniversalTime() Is doing the same thing ?

Comment: Yes, that makes it (*the local date with gmt offset*) a UTC date. Do keep in mind that for historical dates/times this is usually preferred. For scheduling (future dates/times) it could cause issues and it is preferred to store the local datetime along with timezone information. This is because timezones could change in the future before the selected time has passed.

Comment: Directly related: [Storing UTC is not a Silver Bullet](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2019/03/27/storing-utc-is-not-a-silver-bullet/)

Answer (score 1):

Greenwich Mean Time (GMT) is often interchanged or confused with Coordinated Universal Time (UTC). But GMT is a time zone and UTC is a time standard.
For Detail check this link:
http://cartfulldeal.com/Question/Details/14/the-difference-between-gmt-and-utc